# Integration tests with selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, grid, integration-testing

I would like to setup a selenium grid and execute my integration tests in parallel. The selenium grid is up and running using a Docker compose file.

So far I have tried two approaches:

1. Use the junit ParallelComputer
2. Use the maven-failsafe-plugin

With the first approach, the test are launched but the ParallelComputer exists and all the requests to the grid are dropped. This is how I call the *test* that executes the *tests in parallel*:

```
public class Suite {
 @Test
 public void  parallelTest() {
  final Class[] testClasses = findClasses();
  final Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), testClasses);
 }
}
```

With the second approach the tests take too long to execute, and at the end my containers go to sleep. This is how I have defined the plugin:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.21.0</version>
  <configuration>
   <includes>                               
    <include>com/integrationtest/**</include>
   </includes>
   <parallel>classes</parallel>
   <threadCount>40</threadCount>
  </configuration>
 <executions>
</plugin>
```

I would like the first version to work over the first one as I would like to do some programmatically setup before executing the tests. Could you please advice ?

Thanks

Comment: `I would like the first version to work over the first one` which version are you exactly preferring?

Comment: Sorry , the first approach with the ParallelComputer but at the end whatever it works ^^

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the number of threads created with either the maven-failsafe-plugin or the ParallelComputer instance.

The hub of the selenium grid had too many requests waiting, at some point some of them timed out thus making all following tests exit abruptly.

To workaround the issue I changed the configuration for the maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
 <parallel>classes</parallel>
 <perCoreThreadCount>1</perCoreThreadCount>
 <threadCountClasses>4</threadCountClasses>
```

For the moment I am testing the grid with only one node and 5 instances in the node. It seems to work for most of the tests, but for some of the test I have a UnreachableBrowserException, still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

In a parallel running, we need to consider following things

1. Every test should be unique not dependent
2. Test should not take exceed more than 10 mins
3. Grid machine CPU utilization should not exceed 70%.
4. If your machine capable of handling 5 instances and 3 concurrent sessions, go for 4 instances.

[image]